# Changing aprox 12000 image positions in magento automaticly?

Tags: magento-1.9, image, sort

I have a question.
i have a magento webshop (1.9.2.2) containing aprox 12000 products.
all these products have multiple images.

Now we have the folowing problem:
a lot of images have a wrong sort order.
(Base_image should be 0, the small_image 1 and the media_image 2)
Also the base_image should also be set as thumbnail.

Now some Base_images have the right position and are set as base and thumb
but there are also base_images with a wrong position (3 or 4) and are not set as thumb aswell.
manually sorting out 12000 products is a lot of work so im looking for a way to import the sort order for all these products.
(We use magmi v0.7.22 for importing our csv files into magento)

Does anyone know a way to "set things straigt" ?